# How to cut string from start to second last dot of the string?

Tags: php, regex, mbstring

I have some string, for example:

```
cats, e.g. Barsik, are funny. And it is true. So,
```

And I want to get as result:

```
cats, e.g. Barsik, are funny.
```

My try:

```
mb_ereg_search_init($text, '((?!e\.g\.).)*\.[^\.]');
$match = mb_ereg_search_pos();
```

But it gets position of second dot (after word "true").

How to get desired result?

Comment: Your title is misleading as you need to match up to the first full stop that indicates the end of the sentence. Here is a naive approach: `'~(?<!\be\.g)\.(?=\s+\p{Lu})~'` (to be used with `preg_match`). However, you might need some kind of an NLP package.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks

Comment: There are other abbreviations, this won't work in all cases.

Comment: You can `preg_match` with [`(?:\b\w\.|[^.])+\.`](https://regex101.com/r/xN3sU5/1) to get the desired output. `\b` matches a *word boundary*, `\w` *a word character*. How about `Mr. Higgins`...

Comment: Long story but works: [https://3v4l.org/l3ibc](https://3v4l.org/l3ibc)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, please, post your comment as answer, it is best. In my case perfectly works modifiaction for Russan: `preg_match('/(?=((?<!т\.н)(?<!т\.к)(?<!e\.g)))\.(?=\s+\p{L})/iu', $text, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a naive approach works for you, I am posting an answer. However, please note that detecting a sentence end is a very difficult task for a regex, and although it is possible to some degree, an NLP package should be used for that.

Having said that, I suggested using

```
'~(?<!\be\.g)\.(?=\s+\p{Lu})~ui'
```

The regex matches any dot (`\.`) that is not preceded with a whole word `e.g` (see the negative lookbehind `(?<!\be\.g)`), but that is followed with 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with 1 uppercase Unicode letter `\p{Lu}`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ6hB9/1)

The case insensitive `i` modifier does not impact what `\p{Lu}` matches.

The `~u` modifier is required since you are working with Unicode texts (like Russian).

To get the index of the first occurrence, use a `preg_match` function with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag. Here is a bit simplified regex you supplied in the comments:

```
preg_match('~(?<!т\.н)(?<!т\.к)(?<!e\.g)\.(?=\s+\p{L})~iu', $text, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

See the lookaheads are executed one by one, and at the same location in string, thus, you do not have to additionally group them inside a positive lookahead. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ6hB9/2).

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/o0C8zD):

```
$re = '~(?<!т\.н)(?<!т\.к)(?<!e\.g)\.(?=\s+\p{L})~iu';
$str = "cats, e.g. Barsik, are funny. And it is true. So,"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $match[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to get substring from start to second last `.` position of the initial string:

- using `strrpos` and `substr` functions:

  ```
  $str = 'cats, e.g. Barsik, and e.g. Lusya are funny. And it is true. So,';
  $len = strlen($str);
  $str = substr($str, 0, (strrpos($str, '.', strrpos($str, '.') - $len - 1) - $len) + 1);

  print_r($str);  // "cats, e.g. Barsik, and e.g. Lusya are funny."
  ```
- using `array_reverse`, `str_split` and `array_search` functions:

  ```
  $str = 'cats, e.g. Barsik, and e.g. Lusya are funny. And it is true. So,';
  $parts = array_reverse(str_split($str));
  $pos = array_search('.', $parts) + 1;
  $str = implode("", array_reverse(array_slice($parts, array_search('.', array_slice($parts, $pos)) + $pos)));

  print_r($str);  // "cats, e.g. Barsik, and e.g. Lusya are funny."
  ```